# Error in my local weblogic server while running Spring Application

Tags: spring, server, weblogic

I would like to know why I cant run my application ?. I can't understand the reason where is the exception here !. 
The exception trace:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot establish connection. [Root exception is oracle.rc.asadapter.connection.ConnectionException: Cannot establish connection.]
at oracle.tip.tools.ide.fabric.asbrowser.SOARootContextProvider.listBindingsImpl(SOARootContextProvider.java:33)
at oracle.rc.asadapter.context.spi.AbstractContextProvider.listBindings(AbstractContextProvider.java:133)
at oracle.rc.asadapter.context.spi.DefaultMutableAppServerContext$ContextProviderSupport$3.method(DefaultMutableAppServerContext.java:384)
at oracle.rc.asadapter.context.spi.DefaultMutableAppServerContext$ContextProviderSupport$MethodCall.invoke(DefaultMutableAppServerContext.java:421)
at oracle.rc.asadapter.context.spi.DefaultMutableAppServerContext$ContextProviderSupport.listBindings(DefaultMutableAppServerContext.java:381)
at oracle.rc.asadapter.context.spi.DefaultMutableAppServerContext$ContextProviderSupport.access$500(DefaultMutableAppServerContext.java:314)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is there anything I am missing ?. Thankx !.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run your application because your integrated weblogic server doesn't start. From what I see in your screenshots, it seemes that the path to your jre "bin\java" is not valid and cannot be found. Check your JAVA_HOME environmental variable to see if it is pointing to the correct value. If it is correct you can try to recreate your default domain in JDeveloper

Comment: Nicolas. Thnk you very much for your answer !. I did this before checking you answer but because I have several programs that use the JDK / JRE, they didn't start after the change (obviously due to the compatibility I believe)... I'll be posting what it appears to me while opening the Eclipse IDE... Thankx again... And yes... I could open an start the weblogic server !!! :D

Comment: Hi Nicolas !. I realized that and modifified and it's working... There is one details: It seems as If I override the jdk dir of all the apps that use java (netbeans, eclipse, for ex) and now none of them are working... Only my JDeveloper 11... I should lool how to modify only for this apps... Thankx again for your help...